# Cannot retrieve value of dynamically created textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

Good Day!

I'm creating dynamic textboxes. The number of textboxes that should be created depends on the number of column elements my XML has. I can create the textboxes, my problem is retrieving the value of each textboxes on a button click. Could you help me with this?

Here is my code for creating textboxes:

```
foreach (XMLClasses.column col in columns.ToList())
{
    Literal lt = new Literal();
    TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
    Label lbl = new Label();

    lt.Text = "<br/>";
    lbl.Text = col.title + ":";
    lbl.Width = Unit.Pixel(200);
    txtbox.ID = "txtbox_" + col.id;
    txtbox.Width = Unit.Pixel(200);

    Panel1.Controls.Add(lt);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(txtbox);
}
```

Here is my code for retrieving:(button_click)

```
foreach (XMLClasses.column col in columns.ToList())
{
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    Panel pnl = new Panel();
    ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
    if(cph != null)
    {
        pnl = (Panel)cph.FindControl("Panel1");
        if (pnl != null)
        {
            txt = (TextBox)pnl.FindControl("txtbox_" + col.id);
            if (txt != null)
            {
                value = txt.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                value = "NOOOO";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the value `"NOOOO"`. Am I missing something??

Comment: Pause in the debugger and look at the panels `Controls` collection, see if the textboxes are in there. Have a look at the IDs, do they match what you're providing?

Comment: Set the property `ClientMode = Static` of the generated `TextBox`.The try

Comment: Textboxes aren't there :( @DGibbs
What should i do?

Comment: i tried setting it to static, im still getting the value = "NOOOOO" @lqbal

Comment: You need to recreate it on pre-init function of page.

Comment: can you post your HTML Code and code from reading xml to creating textboxes dynamically ?

Comment: @Danielle : if you re-create it on pre-init then how would you get changed values of the text boxes ?

Comment: Not related to the problem. This Assigning: `TextBox txt = new TextBox();` And `Panel pnl = new Panel();` its Unnecessary.

Comment: @lomed : even finding control Panel1 is also not necessary.

Comment: Yeah right, those aren't necessary. I'm gonna remove those lines from my code. Thanks! :)
Sorry for being so ignorant, im just new to ASP.Net. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @danielle please to help :).